# Left and center align items in a div?

Tags: html, css

How can I layout the contents of a div with one element centred and the other aligned left.

I've tried flexbox - not possible without adding a hidden 3rd element and justifying content.

I've also tried text align on parent but then everything is aligned in one way (centered or left).

HTML:

```css
.left{

}

.center{

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    I'm left aligned
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    I'm center aligned
  </div>
</div>
```

### Edit

I'm aligning the divs themselves, and centered relative to parent.

Comment: Are you trying to align the actual text inside the divs, or the divs themselves?

Comment: Im aligning the divs themselves, and centered relative to parent.

Comment: So both divs would be in the same row, but the first div would be on the left, and the second div would be in the center, next to it? With an empty space on the right-hand side?

Comment: That is correct. Would love a flexbox solution but doubt its possible without an extra hidden element.

Comment: I'll work on a solution, but depending on the browser support you need, you can check out CSS grid.

Comment: @panthro - probably just needs more information or a drawing

Comment: Needs wide support.

Comment: I didn't downvote your question, but I assume it's been downvoted since it's a *relatively* simple thing to solve and usually doesn't require a SO post. Though, I appreciate that you may be new to coding

Comment: @panthro What is the issue my answer?

Comment: You don't need flexbox if you're just lining up elements like that. Just set the divs to inline-block and set their width to be a third of the container. 
.container > div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33.33%;
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use flex and :after element for the hidden element:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.container:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  flex: 1;
}

.left,
.center {
  border: 1px solid #0F0;
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    I'm left aligned
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    I'm center aligned
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: probably need text-align-left on your .left

Comment: @Pete yes, but i tthink it's easy for this one, the difficult part is to get the div aligned

Answer (score -2):

**RESULT**
[image]

> How can I layout the contents of a div with one element centred and
>   the other aligned left.

You can use % based widths and just divide it up like so

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  //text-align: center;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%
}

.right {
  float:left;
  width:33.33%;
  text-align:right;
}

.center {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    I'm left aligned
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    I'm center aligned
  </div>
  <div class="right">
  An examplatory div...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 3 down votes because it doesn't work. The left item is not aligned left, nor is the centre, it's just been pushed there.

Comment: The divs ARE aligned correctly, the text simply has text-center

Comment: @panthro Check the answer again, clearly you can't see what the code is doing so now I have made it even more obvious. **THIS IS AND WAS THE  FIRST WORKING SOLUTION**

Comment: Whilst floats are looked down upon these days, I still maintain the fact that this solution does indeed work and was the first working solution.